# Why is it that my button id on the third screen has the same button id on the first screen?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

hello this is my App3Activity class in which from App2Activity screen it will then navigate to that class. Luckily i can already switch screens. From my Screen1 - Screen2 to Screen 3 but on my first screen i have 3 buttons. On my quit button it has an id name and my button on Screen3 always has the same id name on my first screen?

App3Activity class
    package com.example.fillmeapp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class App3Activity extends Activity {

Button button;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main3);

}

}
```

my AppActivity class

```
package com.example.fillmeapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

Button button;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton1();
        addListenerOnButton2();
        addListenerOnButton3();
    }



    public void addListenerOnButton1() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   
            }


        });

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton2() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, App3Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   

                            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,         R.raw.sound_2); //create audio object
                            mediaPlayer.start(); 
            }           

        });

    }
    public void addListenerOnButton3(){

    button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.quit);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Whats the `issue` you face.

Comment: when i click the quit button to my main screen it navigates directly to my 3rd screen in which the function should have been to quit/ exit the app. At first I run it perfectly but now it has that effect. thank you for helping out

Comment: you want to `Exit` the app.okay try this `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);` to exit the app instead of `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with same id's. Only one thing is that you must have only one unique id in one layout.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the activities are in stack.When you give `System.exit(0);` current activity closed and previous activity comes in forground.If you want to exit the application.

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```